# Link triggers 404 instead of triggering FancyBox in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using FancyBox 2.1.5 and have it set up quite simply as such:

```
<a class='fancybox' href='#box'>Read More</a>

<div class="hiddencontent" id="box"></div>
```

This works fine in al browsers but IE 7.

When I click the link in IE 7 FancyBox doesnt trigger - the browser just tries to find `mysite.com/#box`

Is there any trick to getting this to work in IE 7?

**Fancy Box Script**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        width   : 560,
        height  : 660,
        fitToView : false,
        autoSize : false
    })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please don't support IE7 so it dies sooner.

Comment: @thenewseattle : if you want to talk about cross-browser compatibility you have to tame IE ;)

Comment: @meltindog : I bet you have a js error that other browsers may overlook but IE. Post your jQuery code

Comment: @thenewseattle in only I could...if only

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/QUcPP/show/ works in IE7 so maybe fancybox is not the one triggering the error but another script. If you share a link to a demo page that reproduces the issue, I could tell you what